# is it possible to specify the registry in GitHub actions docker/build-push-action v3

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am using this GitHub actions script to push image to repo:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up QEMU
      uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2

    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

    - name: Login to Docker Hub
      uses: docker/login-action@v2
      with:
        registry: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}
        username: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD }}

    - name: Build and push
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
      with:
        push: true
        tags: pro/cv:latest
```

the build process shows error:

```
buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to push pro/cv:latest: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized
```

I think the `docker/build-push-action@v3` pushed to the docker repo by default but I need to push to custom repo. So I tried to specify the registry with `docker/build-push-action@v3`, seems the v3 has removed the registry. I have already tried to read the [official document](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/tree/v3/) and did not found how to specify the custom registry repo. is it possible to specify the custom repo?

Comment: Isn't that `registry: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}` in your docker login step the right one where you want to push your image?

Comment: The login action should take care of that. See its [usage](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#usage) docs.

Comment: I think the issue is with your credentials. Docker login action should be able to authenticate you if your credentials have the right permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out the tags specify the full path will fixed this issue:

```
- name: Build and push
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
  with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}/reddwarf-pro/cv:latest
```

Comment: I have the same issue but in my case I'm not only pushing to the registry but I have to pull the base image through the same registry. So this works here but I do really need to set the registry mirror and  can't figure it out.